# Access denied www-data@localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `Jquery.load` to load an external file with html/php content into one div.  It loads the file, and displays what it's supposed to except it says `access denied www-data@localhost password: no` where it should be echoing some content.

I know that the main page, not the one being loaded, is connected to the db using `require_once("assets/functions/config.php");` to call on my php file that contains the connection.

What am I doing wrong?  It's probably simple, and I'm overlooking something.

EDIT:  Okay on the index.php above `<html>` I have:

```
 <?PHP
    require_once("assets/functions/config.php");
    //if ($notInstalled == 1) header("Location: install");
    require_once("assets/functions/functions.php");
    if ($users->checkAuth() == 0) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
    }
    $currentUser = $_COOKIE['vetelixir_username'];
 ?>
```

config.php is as follows:

```
<?
// MySQL Database
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "dbname";
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";

// Connect to the database
$connection = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die(mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection)or die(mysql_error());
// end MySQL
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#content').load('pages/external.php');
});
```

External File to Load:

```
<div id="div">
<?
    $currentBlah = mysql_query("SELECT `firstname`,`lastname` FROM `blah` ORDER BY `lastname` ASC") or die(mysql_error());

    while($u = mysql_fetch_array($currentBlah)) {

    echo "<div class='clientRow'><span class='name'>".$u['firstname']." ".$u['lastname']."</span></div>";

    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: post some real code plz.

Comment: That looks like a MySQL authentication denied message.  Are you authenticating against your database correctly?  This really has nothing to do with jQuery and potentially little to do with PHP.  Debug into your code and see how you're connecting to the database.

Comment: Means your `.php` didn't login to your mysql successfully, double check pls.

Comment: If it's making a database connection, it seems that the function is trying to use `www-data` as the username to connect to the database, and your database server (likely MySQL given that message) doesn't allow access to the user `www-data` coming from `localhost` (the box itself). Check your database users and your configuration for the database connection, you are either using the wrong username, or not supplying a password when you have to.

Comment: Okay I edited the question, and added some code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the php script that your jQuery function is calling is trying (and failing) to open an SSH session.